# Use Java 7's Objects.equals to compare fields?

Tags: java, performance

I was just generating some equals methods and was wondering if it would be advisable to use the Objects.equals() method to compare fields with Java 7.

Eclipse generates equals like this:

```
public class A
{
    private String a;
    private String b;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if(this == obj)
            return true;
        if(obj == null)
            return false;
        if(getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        A other = (A)obj;
        if(a == null)
        {
            if(other.a != null)
                return false;
        }
        else if(!a.equals(other.a))
            return false;
        if(b == null)
        {
            if(other.b != null)
                return false;
        }
        else if(!b.equals(other.b))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And i was wondering, if this would be good practice:

```
public class A
{
    private String a;
    private String b;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if(this == obj)
            return true;
        if(obj == null)
            return false;
        if(getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        A other = (A)obj;
        return Objects.equals(a, other.a) && Objects.equals(b, other.b);
    }
}
```

What do you think? I tried to test the performance of it, but it showed no difference..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's a good practice. This way the `equals` method looks much clearer without any drawbacks except additional method call which in most cases will be easily inlined by JIT compiler. Please note that `Objects.equals` appeared first in Java 7, not Java 8.

Comment: Note also that `Objects.hashcode(T... obj);` is a great addition to it.

Comment: Yes, and that you should always implement `hashCode` when overriding `equals`.